# Compile Nmap as static binary

Tags: compilation, static, nmap

I am trying to install Nmap as a static binary.  I have tried several configure/make stanzas.  The error changes but the problem is the `nsock` dependency included in the Nmap source code.

I have a static binary for openssl and static lib for zlib.

Here is the latest stanzas and error (Note: long commands posted on multi-line for readability, in reality, they are 1 liners):

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/laura/zlib-1.2.11 
          -I/opt/laura/openssl-1.1.0h_bis 
          -I/opt/laura/openssl-1.1.0h_bis/include
          -I./liblinear 
          -I./liblua 
          -I./libdnet-stripped/include 
          -I./libpcap 
          -I./nbase 
          -I./nsock 
          -I./nsock/include" LDFLAGS="-L/opt/laura/zlib-1.2.11 
          -L/opt/laura/openssl-1.1.0h_bis 
          -L./liblinear 
          -L./liblua 
          -L./libpcap 
          -L./nbase 
          -L./nsock" 
LIBS="-ldl" 
./configure --prefix=/opt/laura/nmap-7.70 
            --with-libz=/opt/laura/zlib-1.2.11/ 
            --with-openssl=/opt/laura/openssl-1.1.0h_bis/include/ 
            --with-libnsock=/opt/src/nmap-7.70/nsock

NMAP IS A POWERFUL TOOL -- USE CAREFULLY AND RESPONSIBLY
Configured with: ndiff zenmap nping openssl zlib libssh2 lua ncat
Configured without: localdirs nmap-update
Type make (or gmake on some *BSD machines) to compile.

make LDFLAGS="-L/opt/laura/zlib-1.2.11 
              -L/opt/laura/openssl-1.1.0h_bis 
              -L/opt/src/nmap-7.70/nsock -static"
[...]
```

Compiling nmap

```
rm -f nmap
g++ -L/opt/laura/zlib-1.2.11 -L/opt/laura/openssl-1.1.0h_bis -L/opt/src/nmap-7.70/nsock -static -o nmap charpool.o FingerPrintResults.o FPEngine.o FPModel.o idle_scan.o MACLookup.o nmap_dns.o nmap_error.o nmap.o nmap_ftp.o NmapOps.o NmapOutputTable.o nmap_tty.o osscan2.o osscan.o output.o payload.o portlist.o portreasons.o protocols.o scan_engine.o scan_engine_connect.o scan_engine_raw.o scan_lists.o service_scan.o services.o NewTargets.o TargetGroup.o Target.o targets.o tcpip.o timing.o traceroute.o utils.o xml.o  main.o -lnsock -lnbase -lpcre libpcap/libpcap.a libssh2/lib/libssh2.a -lssl -lcrypto -lz libnetutil/libnetutil.a ./libdnet-stripped/src/.libs/libdnet.a  ./liblinear/liblinear.a -ldl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnsock
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [nmap] Error 1
```

The nsock dir has the following content:

```
include  nsock.vcxproj  src  tests
```

In src dir is located the configure and nsock.h is located in include dir.

Any help?

KR

Answer (score 1):

Nsock is always linked statically in Nmap. Using the `--with-lib*` options indicates where those libs are *installed*, but you've pointed it at the *source*. Just take the `--with-libnsock` option out of your configure line and it should build just fine. You'll probably also want to add `--with-lib{pcap,pcre,z,ssh2,dnet,lua,linear}=included` to build and statically-link the included libraries (unless you have static libraries built and installed elsewhere you would like to link to).